# Mathematica internal number formats and precision

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, number-formatting

Tangentially related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4939616/181759) question, what exactly is happening here with the number formatting?

```
In[1]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*10^-270
Out[1] := 3.12987`*^-270

In[2]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*10^-271
Out[2] := 3.1298700000000003`*^-271
```

If you use `*10.^` as the multiplier the transition is where you would naively expect it to be:

```
In[3]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*10.^-16
Out[3] := 3.12987`*^-16

In[4]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*10.^-17
Out[4] := 3.1298700000000004`*^-17
```

whereas `*^` takes the transition a bit further, albeit it is the machine precision that starts flaking out:

```
In[5]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*^-308
Out[5] := 3.12987`*^-308

In[6]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*10.^-309
Out[6] := 3.12987`15.954589770191008*^-309
```

The base starts breaking up only much later

```
In[7]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*^-595
Out[7] := 3.12987`15.954589770191005*^-595

In[8]  := InputForm @ 3.12987*^-596
Out[8] := 3.1298699999999999999999999999999999999999`15.954589770191005*^-596
```

I am assuming these transitions relate to the format in which Mathematica internally keeps it's numbers, but does anyone know, or care to hazard an educated guess at, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are wondering as to when the InputForm will show more than 6 digits. If so, it happens haphazardly, whenever more digits are required to "best" represent the number obtained after evaluation. Since the evaluation involves explicit multiplication by 10^(some power), and since the decimal input need not be (and in this case is not) exactly representable in binary, you can get small differences from what you expect.

```
In[26]:= Table[3.12987*10^-j, {j, 10, 25}] // InputForm

Out[26]//InputForm=
{3.12987*^-10,
 3.12987*^-11, 
 3.12987*^-12, 
 3.12987*^-13, 
 3.12987*^-14, 
 3.12987*^-15, 
 3.12987*^-16, 
 3.1298700000000004*^-17, 
 3.1298700000000002*^-18, 
 3.12987*^-19, 
 3.12987*^-20, 
 3.1298699999999995*^-21, 
 3.1298700000000003*^-22, 
 3.1298700000000004*^-23, 
 3.1298700000000002*^-24, 
 3.1298699999999995*^-25}
```

As for the *^ input syntax, that's effectively a parsing (actually lexical) construct. No explicit exact power of 10 is computed. A floating point value is constructed and it is faithful as possible, to the extent allowed by binary-to-decimal, to your input. The InputForm will show as many digits as were used in inputting the number, because that is indeed the closest decimal to the corresponding binary value that got created.

When you surpass the limitations of machine floating point numbers, you get an arbitrary precision analog. It no longer is machinePrecision but actually is $MachinePrecision (that's the bignum analog to machine floats in Mathematica).

What you see in InputForm for 3.12987*^-596 (a decimal ending with a slew of 9's) is, I believe, caused by Mathematica's internal representation involving usage of guard bits. Were there only 53 mantissa bits, analogous to a machine double, then the closest decimal representation would be the expected six digits.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: +1 for using `haphazardly` while describing software behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. The transition to arbitrary precision has always confounded me, especially when I have to write large amounts of data to a file and suddenly ~16 characters of precision data are added to every number!

Comment: @Timo 16 characters seems excessive. Do you mean the number you get is around 16 bytes larger than a machine double? Or that you observe that guard bit phenomenon? If the numbers in question are in fact within the size range of machine doubles then feel free to post or send me an example, as it may indicate a problem either in your code or in Mathematica's Put or Export, whichever you are using.

Comment: I mean the expansion from, e.g., 2.3' to 2.3'15.956428462957535 . That brings a significant overhead to the file size. I'll make a separate question for what my actual problem is.

Comment: the question is here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4955429/181759 I would appreciate you having a look. I don't think it qualifies as a bug, but maybe as a feature request.